# Copy a directory and all its contents function?

Tags: perl, copy

To start, I know that there's a library File::Copy::Recursive which has an equivalent function.  Unfortunately, I'm currently working on a server where I don't have the freedom to install libraries, and convincing the person who can is not practical.

I'm trying to write a function which will copy all the contents of a directory, including subdirectories and their contents, to a new, empty directory.  Here's my complete code now:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Copy;

# To use: rec_cpy (sourcedir, destdir)
sub rec_cpy {
  my $sourcedir = $_[0];
  my $destdir = $_[1];
  # open the directory
  opendir(DIR, $sourcedir) or die "Failed to open $sourcedir\n";
  my @files = readdir(DIR);
  closedir(DIR);
  # iterate over contents of directory
  foreach my $filename (@files) {
   if(-d $filename && $filename ne "." && $filename ne ".." ) {
    # if a subdirectory, make the directory and copy its contents
    mkdir "$destdir/$filename";
    rec_cpy("$sourcedir/$filename","$destdir/$filename");
    }
    else {
      # if anything else, copy it over
      copy ("$sourcedir/$filename","$destdir/$filename");
    }
  }
  return;
}

rec_cpy("test1", "test2");
mkdir "itried";
```

"test1" is a directory which contains a file and a directory, which contains a file (all have unique names).  "test2" is an empty but extant directory.

When I run this, I get an error "'test1/..' and 'test2/..' are identical (not copied) at rec_cpy.pl line 26," which makes sense (since they both already exist and already have ".." in them).  However, when I open up test2, the directory from test1 copied as a directory, NOT as a file, yet "itried" gets created as a directory without a problem.  What's going on?

Comment: Depending on licensing, you could just include the code in your project, or you could download it and manually install in a subfolder of your project (e.g. a `lib/` folder).

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to end up doing, but I'm still confused as to why my code detects the directory as a file.

Answer (score 2):

You just made 2 mistakes :

- If this test `(-d $filename && $filename ne "." && $filename ne ".." )` fails, it means `$filename` is either not a directory **or** it's "." or "..". You forgot about that last possilities. A way of correcting this is to put `$filename ne "." && $filename ne ".."` after testing `-d $filename` (see the code bellow).
- You need to check if `"$sourcedir/$filename"` is a dir, and not just `$filename`.

So the foreach loop with this two problems corrected :

```
foreach my $filename (@files) {
    if(-d "$sourcedir/$filename") {
        if ($filename ne "." && $filename ne ".." ) {
            # if a subdirectory, make the directory and copy its contents
            mkdir "$destdir/$filename";
            rec_cpy("$sourcedir/$filename","$destdir/$filename");
        }
    }
    else {
        # if anything else, copy it over
        copy ("$sourcedir/$filename","$destdir/$filename");
    }
}
```

---

But as @oldtechaa mentionned, you could include the code of File::Copy::Recursive in your project.